# Buildozer Error "pkg-config location is not supported on linux for prerequisite: openssl"

Tags: sudo, android, openssl

I want to make apk file for android, using Buildozer. This my game: https://youtu.be/t7jtlkXcS68
I'm getting an error: [WARNING]: pkg-config location is not supported on linux for prerequisite: openssl

I have installed OpenSSL but there is no 'openssl.pc' on my computer. I have installed libssl-dev also.

How can I fix this buildozer build error?